# parsing float numbers through Arduinos Serial connection

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial, arduino-uno

I'm using an Arduino Uno to control pulses from a magnetic sensor. Before operation begins, I need to read two floats as parameters for my computations.
My arduino code is the following:

```
int i=0;
while (true) //wait until parameters are read
{
  if (Serial.available())
  {
    inData[i++]=Serial.parseFloat();
  }
    if (i>=initLength) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

If I use the built-in Serial monitor there is no problem, I can enter i.e. "1.5 2.5" and push the Enter key and the parameters are read correctly. 
But if I use my own python program it doesnt work anymore. I'm using pyserial to send the parameters to the Arduino.

```
sstr='{0} {1}'.format(1.5,2.5)
ser.write(sstr.encode('ascii'))
ser.flush()
```

If I send the data using python, the following is saved to the variables:

```
inData[0]: 0.00
inData[1]: 1.5
```

Seems to be some kind of encoding problem but I haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 1):

You don't terminate your python string with a character that would signal to [Arduino's Serial.parseFloat()](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/ParseFloat) that the floating point number 2.5 is also finished. pyserials's `Serial.flush` does not ensure that either, it only means to make sure the serial data that was buffered is "put on the wire". For that reason, you are not seeing `inData[2] = 2.5`, even though it is almost there. Basically the Arduino is still waiting for characters, because it doesn't know if 2.5 is terminated or if more digits might still follow.

As for `inData[0]` being 0.00, I can only guess that it is the remains of an unfinished parsing.

Try

```
sstr='{0} {1}\n'.format(1.5,2.5)
```

And make sure to have an empty serial connection from the start.